# how to scrape business name from xpath and get the file in csv

Tags: python, scrapy

```
i am trying to scrape yellow page by using scrapy and python getting all other result right but not getting the business name
```

tried changing xpath even tried css selector but not getting proper result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about yellowpages.com then you can scrape the names of businesses from a searchresult-page by using the css selector with the following tags: 'div.info .business-name span::text'

So for example, you could start a scrapy shell and go to a search result:

```
scrapy shell "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=doctors&geo_location_terms=berlin"
```

Then type the following into your scrapy shell:

```
response.css('div.info .business-name span::text').extract()
```

You should now receive a list of all business names of that specific page.

But watch out, yellowpages.com explicitly states in their robots.txt that scrapy is not allowed on any of their pages.

Comment: Thank you works fine and sure will take care about your tips